# Ruby alternatives to capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Capistrano has some rough edges.  What are some other packages I should consider?

In case you're curious, I'm using Capistrano for non-web related control, to automate some tests that involve executing commands on a bunch of (virtual) machines.

One task I have is to shut down a VM:

```
desc "Shut down a VM"
task :turn_off_vm do
  sudo 'shutdown -h now'
end
```

The problem is, once the command is executed, cap keeps the ssh connection open, then throws an error when it disappears, which means 2 of my 8 machines don't shut down.

Also, sudo doesn't work the way I'd expect (fabric's sudo does), the following command:

```
sudo 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

fails, because only the "echo" is run as root, not the shell that runs the command, so writing to the file is done as me.

Comment: While Capistrano is Ruby based, your question is more suitable to superuser.com.

Comment: If you have the ability to ssh in as root, you don't need to use sudo if you `set :user, "root"` in your capistrano configuration. That will solve the IO redirection issue.

Comment: Capistrano is not really designed for that kind of use. You may want to look into [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Puppet` might be an equivalent to `Capistrano`

http://www.agileweboperations.com/puppet-vs-capistrano-short-comparison

Comment: Actually, I'm going with Chef, but Puppet is another contender.